# Inspect UI in IntelliJ IDEs

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I want to modify some UI in IntelliJ straight from the code (https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community), but I am having a hard time to identify which panel/class that particular UI component is.

Is there a way to tell "Hey, what panel is beneath the mouse cursor?"? - just like "Inspect element" in a browser.

The particular UI piece is the "file + line number" from the find panel:
[image]

I've added the code from https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community and tried searching by strings found in the "Find" panel, but as I'm not a Java developer, haven't found what I'm looking for.

Comment: What UI framework? JavaFX, Swing, AWT, SWT, Vaadin?

Comment: @BasilBourque The OP is referring to IntelliJ itself, so in a sense the framework *is* IntelliJ.

Comment: @BasilBourque as Mark noted, it's the framework used to develop the IDE itself and I think is based on Swing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When running IntelliJ in internal mode (should be by default in your sandbox), you get the [UI inspector](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/internal-ui-inspector.html) under **Tools > Internal Actions > UI > UI Inspector**.

The specific UI element you are looking for is hard to get this way though, because when transferring focus to the UI inspector you lose the find popup.
My guess is that you are looking for an implementation of [`ItemPresentation`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/core-api/src/com/intellij/navigation/ItemPresentation.java), the one in [`PsiFileImpl`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/c1d5eea5a08b1d67abf65804d3a573f5a25f791e/platform/core-impl/src/com/intellij/psi/impl/source/PsiFileImpl.java#L888%60) might give you a good starting point.

---

**Edit.** You *can* open the UI inspector for any UI element with the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd>, where you click on the element you want to inspect.

Comment: That UI Inspector is what I was looking for, thank you! Will start from your suggestions.

Comment: To enable Internal Actions follow the instruction https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/enabling-internal.html